# Show all result from a list if all value is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a filter of a list.
The code I wrote is this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: 'all',
        textfield: ''
    };
}

render() {
  let filteredPlatform = fullList.filter((el) => {
    return el.gameName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.textfield) >= 0 && el.platform === this.state.value;
  });
  .....
  <Table data={filteredPlatform} />
}
```

The platform value could be *all*, *xbox*, *ps4* and so on.
I would like to show the entire not filtered list (by platform) at the start, because *all* is selected.
Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd generally break this out into a separate function and use an `if` statement to handle the "all" case, but here's another way to do it using the ternary operator:

```
const filteredPlatform = fullList.filter( el =>
               el.gameName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.textfield) >= 0 &&
               (el.platform === this.state.value || "all" === this.state.value )
            );
```

So if `this.state.value` is "all", then we return regardless of `el.platform`. Otherwise we return the filtered version.

Another, more expressive way, is to use 2 filters:

```
const filteredPlatform = fullList
     .filter( el => el.gameName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.textfield) >= 0 )
     .filter( el => el.platform === this.state.value || "all" === this.state.value );
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I voted for this because of the 2 examples.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ternary operator and check if state value is 'all' then assign fullList else assign filtered List

```
let filteredPlatform = this.state.value === 'all' ? fullList : fullList.filter((el) => {
el.gameName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.textfield) >= 0 && el.platform === this.state.value;
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is no selected platform (`all`), the list is not filtered.

```
  let filteredPlatform = this.state.value === 'all'
                         ? fullList : fullList.filter((el) => {
    return el.gameName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.textfield) >= 0 && el.platform === this.state.value;
  });
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the questioner meant - I think we always want to filter by `this.state.textfield`, but the `el.platform` filtering is affected by "all"